# How to save game-progress in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I am developing a website that is a kind of game. The users' progress is saved in a MySQL-database.

I want to go about this by having a table saves with a column save (ID) and a column progress, where progress is of datatype text. When the user starts out, progress is set to (e.g.) '0'. If he proceeds to level 1, progress is set to '0#1', level two makes it '0#1#2'. The order of levels is free and I want to save it. So progress could be '0#4#2#15' and so on.

Is this a good way to do this? I have no experience with SQL and I don't want to do something incredibly stupid. I've read so much confusing info about tables, foreign keys and whatnot...

I want to thank you for your time reading this and I'm looking forward to answers.

Ryan

Comment: Please split this into multiple questions.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean 'cache' rather than 'buffer'?

Answer (score 4):

Answer to your Question 1

I would not approach your problem this way.  I would create 3 tables: a `Levels` table (primary key of 'levelKey'), a `Users` table (primary key of 'userKey') and a `User_Levels` table with a composite key of 'levelKey' and 'userKey'.  When a user completes a level, just insert into the `User_Levels` table.  Then to see if a user has completed a level is a simple select:

```
SELECT 'a' FROM User_Levels WHERE userKey = ? AND levelKey = ?
```

If the number of rows is > 0, the user has completed the level

Comment: This is a much approach in my opinion.  If you need to keep the order in which a level was completed, you could have a third column in User_Levels that has the ordinal value.  For example if User 2 completes Levels 1, 4, and 2 in that order, the table would have for '(userKey, levelKey, ordinalValue)` the entries `(1,1,1), (1,4,2), (1,2,3)`.

Comment: True, I only listed the columns in the answer that is necessary (the keys).  You can tack on any amount of information that describes Levels, Users, or the relationship between the two (User_Levels).

Comment: "This is a much approach" = "watcher's is a much better approach".  Sheesh.

Answer (score 2):

As for Question 2, I'd say the amount of queries is not the problem. After all, you are **writing** data to the database, not accessing it. Personally, I would send a "save" to the database, whenever a user actually completes a level.

watcher has posted a good approach for splitting up the levels and users into different tables. The sequence of progress can be seen from the order the progress gets logged into the User_Levels, so no need to store something like 1#3#4#9

You will probably want to send the save in the background with ajax, so you don't interrupt the game play. Look into [jQuery's $.post method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), for example. Or if your game is in flash, you can use a URLRequest.

Answer (score 1):

About your first question, if the game / levels are non-linear personally I would take a different approach; I would simply add a table which contains a column for the user ID and a column for the level completed. So if user 1 has completed levels 0, 4 and 7, my table would have 3 rows:

```
UID  levels_completed
1    0
1    4
1    7
```

About your other questions, you can use javascript events and ajax to detect the closing of the page but I would not rely on that; I would just run the queries whenever needed. And if your session is destroyed, you are already too late...

Comment: Well, the levels are more like "sections" and there's gonna be a bunch of them. The order is important because the player can go back and forth.
I'm reading the progress into an array when the player resumes the game.
With a large number of users and a large number of sections per user, is that still a good approach?

Comment: @Ryan This is just a basic example but if you want to add more information, you could add columns that contain additional information. Either way operations will be easier on a table like this than on a table with a lot of information compressed into one field.